# How to handle large dropdownlist?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu, formview

Using VB.NET/asp.net, I have a page with a Formview. On the Insert and Edit templates, there are multiple dropdownlists for Depts and People. There are multiple sections in these templates and I would say that there 3 sections for each Dept and People dropdown. I would guess that there are upwards of 100 depts and close to 10000 for the People. The requirement is that if the user does not know the Dept, they then can just choose the People dropdown which would provide the entire 10,000 listing of people.

Needless to say, the pagesize of this page is over 5MB....I already had to increase the default

What are my options in creating a dropdown which can handle this lack of filter and would allow me to have a much more manageable pagesize size? Is there anything in Ajax or even Javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: Use auto complete textbox than drop down, If user doesn't know the department but he must know the people name.

Comment: Even with an auto complete, you can still potentially have too many entries. Your design is wrong.

Comment: @IrishChieftain - care to provide a more thorough response rather than just the "Your design is wrong"...I'm willing to listen.

Comment: Whenever you have that amount of data, you have to design your UI from the ground up to filter it down. Start with departments...

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of tutorials on this. Idea is to have an `autocomplete` control, that is basically a textbox, when you type something , lets say you have typed 'Abc', it will do a `ajax` call to fetch all records matching '`Abc'`, then get results from DB via `ajax`, and show those in selectable div, there you can define events. You don't have to manage anything, except DB call to get required data. The `autocomplete control` will do the job.

Help links -
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AJAX-AutoCompleteExtender-Example-in-ASPNet.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201099/AutoComplete-With-DataBase-and-AjaxControlToolkit